# Как отдавать json генерируемый скриптом браузеру?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, веб-сервер

У меня есть python скрипт который выводит нужную мне информацию прямо в консоль.

А мне хотелось бы поднять минимальные веб-сервер, который вы при переходе по ссылке типа: `http://ip.my.server?parametr1=1&parametr2=2` запускал нужную мне команду и отдавал на экран json

сейчас мой скрипт запускается через консоль такой командой: `myPythonScript parametr1 parametr2`

прощу прощения если вопрос глупый, я только сегодня начал знакомство с Python.

Мой сервер работает на Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0):

Простой сайт можно сделать на `flask` (`pip install flask`)

У вас уже есть скрипт на питоне, пусть будет `myPythonScript.py`. Сейчас он принимает аргументы и запускает по ним логику.

Теперь, чтобы его использовать на сервере у вас 2 пути:

- Вы можете не трогать его и запускать через `subprocess`:

  ```
  from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

  process = Popen([program, 'myPythonScript.py', parametr1, parametr2], stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
  result = process.communicate()[0].decode().strip()
  print(result)
  ```

  Переменные `parametr1` и `parametr2` заранее создаете
- Импортировать его в скрипт сервера и вызывать у него функцию, что обработает параметры:

  ```
  import myPythonScript
  result = myPythonScript.run(parametr1, parametr2)
  print(result)
  ```

  Переменные `parametr1` и `parametr2` заранее создаете. А в `myPythonScript.py` должна быть функция `run`, что принимает параметры и возвращает результат

  А чтобы ограничить код, который при импорте не должен выполняться, добавляете условие `if __name__ == '__main__':` (как у сервера)

Останется, добавить один из вариантов в скрипт сервера и выполнять в `index`

Пример:

```py
from flask import Flask, request


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    args = request.args
    return {
        'status': 'ok',
        'parametr1': args.get('parametr1'),
        'parametr2': args.get('parametr2'),
    }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Перешел по http://127.0.0.1:5000/?parametr1=1&parametr2=2

И сайт вернул `{"parametr1":"1","parametr2":"2","status":"ok"}` с заголовком `Content-Type: application/json`

---

**PS.**

По-умолчанию, `flask` сортирует ключи `json`, чтобы отключить это нужно добавить:

```py
app.config['JSON_SORT_KEYS'] = False
```

Comment: Благодарю за эту информацию! А как отдать в результат выполнения команды **myPythonScript parametr1 parametr2**, она асинхронная

Comment: В функции `index` вызовите ваш код (например как функцию), передавая в нее параметры из `args`, а результат в `return`. Либо, в функции через `subprocess` вызовите скрипт, передавая параметры из `args`, а результат в `return`. Вариант с функцией проще, тем более, и там, и там питон :)

Comment: @iKey, добавил больше информации по запуску. Из похожего, это импорт скрипта в той же папке и обращение к его классам: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/1bf3acaefa32c03bcd7f15c16215dc53a2b9c61d/flask__webservers/url_shortener/main.py#L12 в `db.py` находятся модели таблицы базы данных